# Custom data types in doubly linked list

Tags: c++, types, g++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to use a custom data type in a doubly linked list. I am able to create the list, but when I try to call the insert function, it errors out. What causes this error?

main.cpp:

```
#include "command.h" //my custom class 
#include "doublyLinkedList.h"
int main(){

    //create a queue of jobs:
    doublyLinkedList<command>* queue = new doublyLinkedList<command>;

    //creating a new command:
    command *c = new command();
    c->createCommand();
    c->print();
    const command *d = new command(c->name, c->description, c->shellString);

    queue->insert(*d); //problem line
};
```

doublyLinkedList.h's insert function:

```
template <class Type>
void doublyLinkedList<Type>::insert(const Type& insertItem)
{
nodeType<Type> *current;      //pointer to traverse the list
nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent; //pointer just before current
nodeType<Type> *newNode;      //pointer to create a node
bool found;

newNode = new nodeType<Type>; //create the node
newNode->info = insertItem;  //store the new item in the node
newNode->next = NULL;
newNode->back = NULL;

if(first == NULL) //if the list is empty, newNode is 
                  //the only node
{
   first = newNode;
   last = newNode;
   count++;
}
else
{
    found = false;
    current = first;

    while (current != NULL && !found) //search the list
        if (current->info >= insertItem)
            found = true;
        else
        {
            trailCurrent = current;
            current = current->next;
        }

    if (current == first) //insert newNode before first
    {
        first->back = newNode;
        newNode->next = first;
        first = newNode;
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
          //insert newNode between trailCurrent and current
        if (current != NULL)
        {
            trailCurrent->next = newNode;
            newNode->back = trailCurrent;
            newNode->next = current;
            current->back = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            trailCurrent->next = newNode;
            newNode->back = trailCurrent;
            last = newNode;
        }

        count++;
    }//end else
}//end else
}//end insert
```

The code works for ints and strings, but not for "command" types.

Error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
doublyLinkedList.h: In member function âvoid doublyLinkedList<Type>::insert(const Type&) [with Type = command]â:
main.cpp:34:18:   instantiated from here
doublyLinkedList.h:171:13: error: no match for âoperator>=â in âcurrent->nodeType<command>::info >= insertItemâ
doublyLinkedList.h:171:13: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:232:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator>=(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:315:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator>=(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:365:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator>=(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2621:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator>=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2633:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator>=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2645:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator>=(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
```

Comment: Everytime I post full code, I get scolded...

Comment: Well consider: does it matter that it's a doubly linked list and not a singly linked one?  Try deleting the second link before asking and see.  Does it matter if you push things direct to the head or if you sort it?  Try deleting the sorting code and see.  Hold on: it *did* matter if you tried to sort it?  Smoking gun found.  Your question transforms into *"Why can I compare ints and strings, but not `command` references?"*  You might even answer it yourself... http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're trying to keep the list sorted, however you haven't defined comparison operators for `command`. You need to implement `operator>=` for your type, if you want to use it as is.

It's signature could probably look something like this:

```
bool operator>= (const command& a, const command& b);
```

Comment: Overload the operator? I'll try this and let you know how it works!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading, or any of the other results on the first page when looking for "operator overloading" in Google should help.

Comment: Oh, I've done it before. I was just asking for clarification.

Comment: OK, sorry. Go ahead and give it a try then.

Comment: Where am I overloading the operator, in my doublyLinkedList.h or in my commands.h?

Comment: @Jeff: The place depends on whether you want it to be generally use or only for the list. I would opt for the list since often these comparisons are only sensible for a list and should not be used as general comparison criterion. In the end its a matter of taste

Comment: Though if you start adding the comparison code for each type that you want to use to the doublyLinkedList.h, it could easily get out of control. If it makes sense in general to compare `command`s, go for commands.h, otherwise my recommendation would be to define it wherever you're using the list.

Comment: I was honestly thinking I shouldn't have to overload it at all since im comparing nodes not objects (or do I missunderstand what I have here). But if I overload the function in my commands.h would the doublyLinkedList.h know to use the overloaded boolean operator?

Comment: You're not comparing `node`s, you're comparing `node->info`, which is of type `command` in your case. So if you want your list to be sorted, you should overload it (otherwise you should remove the sorting from the list). Also, doublyLinkedList.h does not need to directly know anything about the overloaded operator, as long as you include commands.h wherever you're using a list of `command`s.